# What are hot research topics for PhD dissertation in Biostatistics?

Tags: biostatistics, careers, phd

I've been thinking of choosing research topics for PhD dissertation in Biostatistics. I wish to know some hot research topics in recent years. As far as I know, some hot research topics  are:

1. High-dimensional data analysis;
2. causal-inference in experiments and observational studies;
3. propensity score matching;
4. Bayesian statistics.
5. Time series;
6. Model selection;
7. Survival data analysis;

**My questions are:**

1. Are there any good literature reviews that summarize recent research trends in Biostatistics?
2. What are must-read review papers for these topics?

Comment: have you checked what topics are being currently published? take, for example, http://arxiv.org/list/q-bio/current

Comment: If I may, I would add on Bayesian methods for large scale genomics.  Huge area of research where I am.

Comment: @mugen, Thanks. I did check those topics. My problem is that I cannot find good review/summary papers about those topics. I can find some for high-dimensional research though. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3092303/

Comment: @ChrisC, definitely I agree.

Comment: I suspect this community might find questions 1 & 2 on topic.  However, question 3 is not appropriate for an SE site and question 4 is a separate issue (although a related one, I admit).  Since your focus seems to be on the first two, I have taken the liberty of deleting the third and fourth in order to stave off the close votes that are accumulating.

Comment: [Approximate Bayesian computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation)

Answer (score 3):

- Leah Welty, [Emerging Trends](http://www.feinberg.northwestern.edu/sites/bcc/docs/2013-lecture/BCCLectureII2013FINAL.pptx), 2013
- Davidian, [Cutting Edge: Emerging trends in biostatistics](http://membercentral.aaas.org/articles/cutting-edge-emerging-trends-biostatistics), 2012
- [Modern Issues and Methods in Biostatistics](https://books.google.com/books?id=3MvOeV-IUH4C&dq=emerging%20trends%20biostatistics&source=gbs_navlinks_s), Springer, 2011